# dynamically created id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need loop in Javascript - when You click on button it add ol tu ul and gave id with number, like this:

```
<ol id="single-task1"></ol>
<ol id="single-task2></ol>
```

And so on...

When I tried whit loop like this:

```
taskNumber = 0;

        for (var i; i<999; i++){
            taskNumber++;
        }

        var ol = document.createElement('ol'); //creating element ol
        taskValue = textField.value; //getting value from user
        taskList.appendChild(ol); //add ol to ul
        ol.id = 'single-task-'+taskNumber;
        ol.innerHTML = taskValue; //add value from user to new ol
```

All ol elements still have "single-task-0"... Probably loop is in wrong place or loop is wrong.

Comment: Do all the creation in the loop instead of after the loop is complete

Comment: You only incrementing taskNumber within the loop. Then, you are only working on one `ol`-element. Try using a debugger within your browser to see what your code is doing.

Comment: Why are you putting `<ol>` elements inside a `<ul>`? Did you mean `<li>`? Do you really need one thousand IDs? Why not simply `taskList.children[taskNumber]`?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing your `taskNumber` and your `i` variable.  Initialize `i = 0` in your loop and use that.  Do all of your work within the loop.  You don't need `taskNumber`.